# Why are loop update of the same row is getting slower and slower?(postges 12)

Tags: postgresql

Loop updates of the same row are getting slower and slower. And updating an indexed field slows them even more. So, considering we are updating the same row, I have some questions:

- Why are loop updates getting slower?
- Why are loop updates of an indexed field ~10 times as slower? (coz single update with index isn't 10 times slower)
- What if it's not a loop but dozens of requests to update one row, will the situation preserve?

Let's init some simple table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_updates
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    update_me integer,
    me_too integer,
    CONSTRAINT test_updates_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX ON test_updates(update_me);
INSERT INTO test_updates(id) VALUES (1);
```

Then loop update unindexed field me_too

```
do $$
declare result record;
begin
    for i in  1..1000 loop 
        explain analyze update test_updates set me_too = i where id = 1 returning * into result;
        raise notice '%', result;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

10 first rows of the output

```
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.566..0.567 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.044..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.036..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.049..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.079..0.080 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)")
```

And 10 last

```
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.052..0.052 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.056..0.057 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.052..0.053 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.068..0.069 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.064..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.060..0.061 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.075..0.076 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.00..6.01 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=1 loops=1)")
```

results increased insignificantly(but if we loop 10000 times then the last update will be 11 times slower).

Here we loop update indexed field update_me.

```
do $$
declare result record;
begin
    for i in  1..1000 loop 
        explain analyze update test_updates set update_me = i where id = 1 returning * into result;
        raise notice '%', result;
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

And 10 first rows

```
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.048..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.026..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.038..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.042..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.047..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.047..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.056..0.058 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.054..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)")
```

And 10 last rows

```
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.479..0.496 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.475..0.493 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.497..0.515 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.483..0.500 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.473..0.491 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.471..0.489 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.478..0.497 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.476..0.494 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.479..0.497 rows=1 loops=1)")
NOTICE:  ("Update on test_updates  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.474..0.492 rows=1 loops=1)")
```

So an indexed field is getting slower 10 times faster.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code block, to begin with?

Comment: @GMB:  In blocks with notice you may see the actual time for 10 first and 10 last updates and blocks with loops are to reproduce my steps. I assume that there could be a problem with code or smth.

Comment: I meant: what is the purpose of the `for` loop? Why are you continuously updating the same row?

Comment: @GMB: actually there is no practical reason for it. I was playing with postgres, and occasionally got this results.

Comment: Well, that's one giant transaction, and each UPDATE will create a new version of the row without any chance for the database to clean out the old ones, because they are still "used" by that transaction. The code makes no sense and is totally unrealistic to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: actually, you've answered my question, thank you)